# Random Number Collisions in Busy Website

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.net website that has the following code:

```
Random r = new Random();

string mustBeUnique = DateTime.Now.Ticks + r.Next(1000);
```

It appears thought that since Random is based off of time, that two requests that happen simultaneously generate the same random number.

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: It seems you're missing the .ToString() method too; correct your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply looking for a unique identifier, I would recommend using a 'Guid' instead.

Its purpose is to be a globally unique identifier:

```
string mustBeUnique = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx

Comment: Great idea, and so obvious as soon as you said it. Thank you solving and simplifying my issue.